# Segmentation fault occurs in linked list while searching for an item that doesnt exist

Tags: c

I'm working on a client/server program where a client inputs name ,last name and phone number. The input functions works well. It adds to a linked list normaly. When I call search function with a phone number that is already in the linked list on the server it works perfectly but when I try to search for a phone number the server crashes stating Segmentation fault when it was supposed to just send to the client that the search was unsuccesful/wasnt found. This error only occurs when the linked list is not empty. If i search for a non existant number in empty list it responds like it should in the if statement.

I've tried so many options but I just dont see where it goes wrong.

Server

```
else if(strcmp(data_char_array,"output") == 0)
        {
            printf("[REQ] Client has requested a search\n");
            return_value = read(client_info, izpis.phone_number, 100);
            entry.phone_number[return_value] = 0;
            
            if(ifExists(izpis.phone_number) == 1)
            {
                write(client_info, "none", 8);
                printf("\n No match found!\n");
            }
            else
            {
                struct phonebook* find = findNum(izpis.phone_number);

                char phone_num[101]; 
                char last_n[31];
                char first_n[31];
                strncpy(phone_num, find->phone_number, 100);
                strncpy(last_n, find->last_name, 30);
                strncpy(first_n, find->first_name, 30);

                write(client_info, "found",10);
                write(client_info, first_n,100);
                write(client_info, last_n,30);
                write(client_info, phone_num, 30);
                printf("\n Request processed succesfully\n");
               
            }
```

```
struct phonebook* findNum(char phone[101]){
    struct phonebook* curr = head;

    if(head == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }

    while(strcmp(curr->phone_number,phone))
    {
        if(curr->phone_number == NULL)
        {
            return NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
    return curr;
}

int ifExists(char phone[101]){
      struct phonebook* curr = head;

    if(head == NULL){
        return 1;
    }

    while(strcmp(curr->phone_number,phone))
    {
        if(curr->phone_number == NULL)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Client

```
char send[11] = "output";
        char recieve[11];
        char name[31];
        char last[31];
        char phone[101];

        while(1)
        {
       
        return_value = write(data_socket, send, strlen(send));
        if (return_value == -1) 
        {
            perror("Error occurred while sending! Error at 0x1!");
            exit(-1);
        }

        return_value = write(data_socket, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
        if (return_value == -1) 
        {
            perror("Error occurred while sending! Error at 0x2!");
            exit(-1);
        }
      
        return_value = read(data_socket, recieve, 11);
        recieve[return_value] = 0;
        printf("Searching: %s\n", recieve);
        if(strcmp(recieve, "found") == 0)
        {
            printf("Search was successful\n");
            return_value = read(data_socket,name,31);
            name[return_value] = 0;
            printf("%s ", name);
            return_value = read(data_socket,last,31);
            last[return_value] = 0;
            printf("%s ", last);
            return_value = read(data_socket,phone,101);
            phone[return_value] = 0;
            printf("%s ", phone);
            break;
```

Comment: this is C not C++, right? Please only tag the language you are using

Comment: Check for end-of-list in your loops: `while(curr && strcmp(curr->phone_number,phone))`

Comment: Yes, that is even written in the description of those tags. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I've tried your suggestion, still throws out the error. But after toying around for a bit I think the problem is in the while loops, I just dont know what currently

Comment: It should be more like `while (cur) { if (!strcmp(cur->phone_number,phone)) return 1; cur = cur->next;} return 0;`

Comment: I've tried and its always the same

Comment: I would expect `ifExists` to return `1` when the item is found and `0` when not found. But it looks like you have it the other way around, so swap the return codes in my previous comment.

Comment: Now it does the opposite. It works normally if the linked list has no items, but crashes if it finds an item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findNum` and `ifExists` are actually duplicates, same process but just return different structure. Would suggest to merge into `findNum` only.

```
struct phonebook* findNum(char phone[101]){
    struct phonebook* curr = head;

    if(head == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }

    while(curr != NULL) {
        if(curr->phone_number != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(curr->phone_number, phone) == 0) {
                return curr;
            } //end if
        } //end if

        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Then, also need to change the function invocation

```
    struct phonebook* find = findNum(izpis.phone_number);
    if(find == NULL) {
        write(client_info, "none", 8);
        printf("\n No match found!\n");
    }
    else {
        //struct phonebook* find = findNum(izpis.phone_number);

        char phone_num[101];
        char last_n[31];
        char first_n[31];
        strncpy(phone_num, find->phone_number, 100);
        strncpy(last_n, find->last_name, 30);
        strncpy(first_n, find->first_name, 30);

        write(client_info, "found",10);
        write(client_info, first_n,100);
        write(client_info, last_n,30);
        write(client_info, phone_num, 30);
        printf("\n Request processed succesfully\n");
    }
```